# Decorated object function is not pickable: it's not the same object as

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

Generally speaking I have a class method which is decorated and I need it be pickled (actually I use `multiprocessing` to call this decorated function), but as code shown below it is erred with message `Can't pickle <function Test.test at 0x7f94b0156b80>: it's not the same object as __main__.Test.test`.

```
import pickle
def dump(data, fpath, protocol=2):
    fdir = os.path.dirname(fpath)
    if not os.path.exists(fdir):
        os.makedirs(fdir)
    with open(fpath, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
def D(f):
    def wrapper(self):
        dump(f, '/tmp/a.dump')
    return wrapper
        
class Test():
    @D
    def test():
        print('test')
aaa = Test()
aaa.test()
```

The error message:

```
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_40891/4137513423.py in <module>
     16         print('test')
     17 aaa = Test()
---> 18 aaa.test()

/tmp/ipykernel_40891/4137513423.py in wrapper(self)
      8 def D(f):
      9     def wrapper(self):
---> 10         dump(f, '/tmp/a.dump')
     11     return wrapper
     12 

/tmp/ipykernel_40891/4137513423.py in dump(data, fpath, protocol)
      5         os.makedirs(fdir)
      6     with open(fpath, 'wb') as f:
----> 7         pickle.dump(data, f)
      8 def D(f):
      9     def wrapper(self):

PicklingError: Can't pickle <function Test.test at 0x7f94b0156b80>: it's not the same object as __main__.Test.test
```

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear about what doesn't work in your example. In short, functions get pickled by name. So `Test.test` needs to be looked up when the pickle file gets reloaded If it isn't the original function any more (because of the decorator), restoring the pickle won't work. Maybe you should give an example of your multiprocessing problem? That might have an actual solution. Your current example code can't really be fixed.